# Form validation Javascript is not responding

Tags: java, javascript, forms, servlets

Seconds ago, it was working, and I did not change anything. My web app is a simple web-app. Javascript is responsible for form validation before it redirects it to the servlet. What did I do wrong?

Form validation is not validating. I am a novice programmer, so please help.

```
// form-validation (javascript)
function validateForm() {
    var firstname = document.forms["myForm"]["förnamn"].value;
    var lastname = document.forms["myForm"]["efternamn"].value;
    var address = document.forms["myForm"]["address"].value;
    var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    var news = document.forms["myForm"]["news"].value;

    if (firstname == null || firstname == "") {
        alert("Var god och fyll i alla fält!");
        return false;
    } else if (lastname == null || lastname == "") {
        alert("Var god och fyll i alla fält!");
        return false;
    } else if (address == null || address == "") {
        alert("Var god och fyll i alla fält!");
        return false;
    } else if (email == null || email == "") {
        alert("Var god och fyll i alla fält!");
        return false;
    } else if (email.indexOf("@hotmail.com") === -1) {
        alert("Skriv in en korrekt mail-address. exempel@hotmail.com");
        return false
    }
}
//]]>
  </script>
  </head>
<body>
<fieldset style="width: 450px; padding: 20px">
    <div id="page">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Abdi Tem</h1>
            <h2>Welcome to my website</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="bar">
            <div class="link">
                <a href="Hem.html">Hem</a>
            </div>
            <div class="link">
                <a href="CV.html">INFO</a>
            </div>
            <div class="link">
                <a href="Kontakt.html">Ḱontakt</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h1>Hyr en programmerare:</h1>
    <form name="myForm" action="ServletProjekt"
        onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" id="myForm">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Ditt namn:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fornamn" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ditt efternamn:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="efternamn" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Din adress:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="address" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Din email:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Är ditt ärende akut?</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="howoften" value="often"
                    checked="checked" />JA <input type="radio" name="howoften"
                    value="not often" />NEJ</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vad vill du ha hjälp med?</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="news" value="Java"
                    checked="checked" />Programmering <input type="checkbox"
                    name="news" value="C" />Felsökning/Debugging</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hur många timmar kommer ditt ärende att ta?</td>
                <td><select name="age">

                        <option>10-20h</option>
                        <option>30-40h</option>
                        <option>50-60h</option>
                        <option>70h+</option>

                </select></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <hr />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Beställ" />
    </form>
</fieldset>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Look at it using Firefox with web developer tools so you can debug and step through the Javascript and look for errors.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Form validation is not validating"? is it posting when incorrect information is entered? Is the browser throwing errors at you? What precisely is not validating?

Comment: @KHeaney It should alert when the field are empty, which it did a couple of minutes ago.

Comment: And what is happening? Is the form action still processing? Is nothing happening on submit? Does the browser developer tools indicate a javascript error on post? Also you seem to be missing a semicolon on your last return statement

Answer (score 0):

onsubmit function() in your form should return true.

Try putting return true after all conditions have been taken care for validations in

```
 function validateForm()
```

Comment: Tried that earlier, the function is still not responding. Thanks anyway!

Comment: document.forms["myForm"]["förnamn"].value, the name is different from the input element, can you verify this, probably breaking the JS

Comment: The corresponding input element is <input type="text" name="fornamn" />

Answer (score 0):

See this:
http://jsfiddle.net/phpadqcr/

I move your javascript code before the closing html tag, inside a <script></script> block and I found a typo here:

```
    var firstname = document.forms["myForm"]["förnamn"].value;
```

You can fix it by replace the "förnamn" with "fornamn".

Answer (score 0):

Two error in code

1)    `["förnamn"]` : unicode character

2)  Semi-column (`;`)missing for last return statement.